# new panel but same window?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, panels

I am currently building a GUI that would give people the option to buy/sell(send/receive basically). What i am trying to achieve is to have the user click on the buy/sell and when they do click on that button it shows new information.

For example. The user clicks on buy, it will bring them to a new panel with a new label new button and etc. I dont want a new window but to have the current window replaced.

```
public class GuiTest {
    private JButton btnpurchase;
    private JPanel panelMain;
    private JButton btnrefund;

    public GuiTest() {
        btnpurchase.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Buying stuff.");
                purchasecontent();
            }
        });
        btnrefund.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Refunding stuff.");
                refundcontent();
            }
        });
    }
    public static void purchasecontent(){
        //enter the amount of the purchase

    }
    public static void refundcontent(){

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GuiTest");
        frame.setContentPane(new GuiTest().panelMain);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(480,320);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

As you can see in the purchasecontent() function i am trying to have it execute but within the same window.

I am currently using the IntelliJ IDE and is using the form designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must avoid to call static methods from your listeners :) It's a bad practice.

In order to implement things easily, your GuiTest has to inherit from JPanel, consider it as your main panel.

To replace the content, get the frame using :

```
JFrame frame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getRoot(component);
```

and set the new content, for example :

```
 btnrefund.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              JFrame frame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getRoot(component);
              frame.setContentPane(new RefundPanel());
            }
        });
```

RefundPanel is supposed to be the panel you want to set in your frame...

Comment: i added your lines in the btnpurchase listener........

frame.setContentPane(new GuiTest().panelPurchase);

getting error - contentPane cannot be set to null.

I also created a form for it and created a JPanel and named it panelPurchase

@BluEOS

Comment: You have to instantiate your object....  private JButton btnpurchase=new JButton("Hello from Purchase Button");

Comment: btnpurchase is already instantiated right under public class. i cant put it in the action listener because the instance cannot be public or private.

Comment: please review this picture     https://imgur.com/PLgzVff           If i dont have the component declaration then it shows up as component cant be resolved. When i run the program it says it gets stuck on line 40 saying it cannot be null

Comment: My mistake, I forgot that IntelliJ is hiding you all the interesting stuff ! The best advice I can give you, is to forget about "designer" tools. Juste write plain Java, it will solve all your issues. Look at small and complete examples like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html

Comment: i understand the basic stuff like buttons labels and radios. im just having trouble loading the new contentpane. should i just instantiate each form as a separate class and then extend it to the original class?

Comment: 1 content - > 1 JPanel.   Create one class for each JPanel :  public class RefundPanel extends JPanel { ...  }